# Where can I find the OS system limit on input lines?

Tags: c

this is more of a design issue question for character buffers. Typically, a lot of programs especially C programs according to C by Discovery 2nd edition deal with a lot of input and output of Strings. On chapter 5, Section 5.3, Page 255  for those that have the book the footnote on that page says:

"The size of a buffer is open to debate. Many programmers will go with an array of 80 cells since few users will type more than that. Others would go with the system limit on input lines."

Where can I find my system limit on input lines? I feel an 80 character buffer is too small a buffer. I need to be able to explain why I choose the size of my buffer in my program project, my professor will want to know a reason.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define DEL 127

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    FILE *fpin = NULL;  //pointer to access open file.
    int iochar = 0; //temporary storage for characters taken from stdin or from a file.
    int edit = 1; //used to indicate an edit corresponding to (1)(2)(3)(4)
    char *inbuffer = malloc(80); //temporary storage to store characters taken from file or stdin
    int offset = 0;//places the character taken from file or stdin in correct location in allocated memory

    if (argc == 1){

        while ((iochar = getchar()) != EOF){
            if(offset > 80){
                printf("Error: Input size to big for this program.\n");
                printf("A line from your file is bigger than 80 characters.\n");
                return 0;
            }

            if((iochar<32 && iochar != 10) || iochar == 127){
                edit = 0;
                if(iochar == DEL){
                    *(inbuffer + offset++) = '^';
                    *(inbuffer + offset++) = '?';
                }
                else{
                    *(inbuffer + offset++) = '^';
                    *(inbuffer + offset++) = (iochar+64);
                }
            }
            else if(iochar > 127 && iochar < 80)
                edit = 0;
            else if(iochar > 31 && iochar < 127)
                *(inbuffer + offset++) = iochar;

            if(iochar == '\n'){
                *(inbuffer + offset++) = '$';
                int limit_char;
                if(offset > 72)
                    limit_char = offset-72; //if line is larger than 72 print last 72 characters in inbuffer
                else
                    limit_char = 0; //if line is smaller than 72, print whatever is in allocated memory inbuffer

                /*Printing out the characters in allocated memory*/
                *(inbuffer + offset) = 0;
                printf("%s",(inbuffer+limit_char));
                putchar('\n');
                offset = 0;
                }
            }
        return edit;
        }

    if (argc == 2){
        fpin = fopen(argv[1], "r");

        while ((iochar = getc(fpin)) != EOF){
            if(offset > 80){
                printf("Error: Input size to big for this program.\n");
                printf("A line from your file is bigger than 80 characters.\n");
                return 0;
            }

            if((iochar<32 && iochar != 10) || iochar == 127){
                edit = 0;
                if(iochar == DEL){
                    *(inbuffer + offset++) = '^';
                    *(inbuffer + offset++) = '?';
                }
                else{
                    *(inbuffer + offset++) = '^';
                    *(inbuffer + offset++) = (iochar+64);
                }
            }
            else if(iochar > DEL && iochar < 80)
                edit = 0;
            else if(iochar > 31 && iochar < DEL)
                *(inbuffer + offset++) = iochar;

            if(iochar == '\n'){
                *(inbuffer + offset++) = '$';
                int limit_char; //used to limit only 72 characters to be printed
                if(offset > 72)
                    limit_char = offset-72; //if line is larger than 72 print last 72 characters
                else
                    limit_char = 0; //if line is smaller than 72

                *(inbuffer + offset) = 0;
                printf("%s",(inbuffer+limit_char));
                putchar('\n');
                offset = 0;
                }
            }
        return edit;
    }
}
```

Comment: The *correct* answer to this depends on what you're trying to do, exactly. Can you show the code, with the buffer that you're trying to determine a fixed size for?

Comment: Random pieces of advice: Unless you're using `getline`, which requires it, there's no need to `malloc()` your buffer. Just make it a static (global) buffer (i.e. `char buf[WHATEVER];`)

Comment: So there is my code. The program essentially takes either input from stdin or from a file and messes with the non-printables and any non ascii characters. It will also print out the last 72 characters of each line. Right now I have 80 bytes allocated.

Comment: If this is homework, and the prof is providing the input file, I would think he would tell you what a reasonable buffer to allocate would be. Otherwise, just pick something "big" and go with it. A 4096-byte buffer is of no concern here.

Comment: That's the thing Jonathan he said as a hint that we should process as much of the line as possible, but what reason would I give for having a 4096 buffer. He says we have to figure that out.

Comment: Then perhaps he wants you to do what `getline` does, and re-allocate & copy the buffer if, at runtime, it is determined to be too small?

Comment: I'm new to c programming so I don't know all the in and outs yet. So does getline allow for file processing and redirection from the command line on a unix machine.

Comment: Check out the manual. It just reads from any old `FILE*`.

Comment: I typically use 4096 these days, partly for the shock value; BUFSIZ and LINE_MAX are semi-plausible alternatives.  A big question is "what will happen to your program if it encounters a line that is N-3, N-2, N-1, N, N+1, N+2, N+3 characters long where your input buffer is N characters?" For some programs, there's no consequence; for others, lines will be miscalculated.  You then have to decide whether it matters.  Some JSON files are enormous and a single line at most (bookmarks files?). What types of 'text' file are you processing?

Comment: Ahh okay. I'll check my C book. Oh, and by the way is there a place I could go check like some glossary of c functions on unix?

Comment: POSIX functions are specified [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/toc.htm); you might need to sign up the first time you use it (I did a long time ago; I don't know whether you still do).  Otherwise, go to [Linux Manual Pages](http://linux.die.net/) or one of the workalike sites.

Comment: If you only need to print out the last 72 characters of the line, you could treat the input buffer as a circular buffer, reading into `inbuffer[79]` then into `inbuffer[0]`, `inbuffer[1]` etc.  The last 72 characters are always available. Incidentally, there's no point in using `malloc()` for an 80-character buffer; go with a fixed allocation. Indeed, on most machines, a 4096 buffer won't cause trouble, though you won't want to go much bigger (a few more powers of 2 won't hurt, but 1 MiB is probably too big) before you think about using dynamic memory allocation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [**`<limits.h>`**](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/limits.h.html), which defines (on UNIX-like platforms):

- `MAX_CANON` - Maximum number of bytes in a terminal canonical input line.
- `MAX_INPUT` - Minimum number of bytes for which space will be available in a terminal input queue; therefore, the maximum number of bytes a portable application may require to be typed as input before reading them.
- `LINE_MAX` - Unless otherwise noted, the maximum length, in bytes, of a utility's input line (either standard input or another file), when the utility is described as processing text files. The length includes room for the trailing .

[`fgets`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fgets.html) suggests using `LINE_MAX` which is 2048 on my Fedora 17 box, and in Cygwin.

See also:

- libc - [Line-Oriented Input](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Line-Input.html)

Comment: Thanks Jonathon, for answering. If I use malloc(MAX_INPUT) in my c program how many bytes will be allocated? My program is going to be fed a gedit file with large lines.

Comment: GCC on both Fedora 17 and Cygwin show 255 for both `MAX_INPUT` and `MAX_CANON`. However, if you're reading from a file, you theoretically shouldn't assume *any* maximum.

Comment: In a modern POSIX environment, you can use [`getline()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html), which will `malloc`/`realloc` a buffer for you.  Otherwise, maybe `fscanf` would better suit your needs, rather than reading the entire line into memory first?

Comment: I'll post my code. I just have to format it correctly. It's the first time I'm posting code on this website.

Comment: Highlight it and click the code format button. It will indent four spaces for you, which makes it code formatted.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, I was about to tab it out myself. Thanks for that tip.